# Nested CakePHP Routing

Tags: cakephp

I'm working on a CMS and would like to configure cake to automatically find the proper page to use based upon the URL. I don't want to have to manually set this and want it to automatically work if I create new pages (based upon slugs).

Let's say I have the following "page layout":

```
News
    -Local
    -World
        -article1
Products
    -Product1
        -details
        -photos
etc
```

So: mysite.com/local/world/article1 would load "Article1". If I added a page under article1 titled "photos", then: mysite.com/local/world/article1/photos would work. Also, mysite.com/products/product1/details would work, etc. Any page I add to the site should be available (it should use a parent/child method). Any tips on making this happen with CakePHP?

Comment: How are you creating pages? Are you using the pages controller and actually creating files, or a custom controller that saves content in the db?

Comment: Also, if you could, share the CakePHP version.

Comment: Latest version of cake. I could have everything go through the "posts" controller...

Comment: Specify that latest version of Cake is 2.4, for those reading this questions years from now.

Comment: You could just create the directories and files directly under app/View/Pages/ and they will be accessible in a default CakePHP install. You need to at least make an attempt at it, before asking questions. For the parent/child structure you could use [tree behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html). Then a custom controller and route configuration to take the url parts and serve the right page from the db. This is a pretty broad question though.